# a com object compiled on visual c++ 6 won't register on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, com, registration

I have a com object project which registers without problems on windows XP. for some reason, when i try to regiser it on windows 7, it gets stuck, and my app can't instantiate the com object.

what seems realy strange to me is that the dependency walker inducates a missing file "x.dll" whereas such file does not even exist. however, the com project has an "x.lib" file with which it compiles the program.

I believe there's some sort of problem with the definitions of dependencies, and can't realy figure out what it is.

Comment: Does it register on Vista? Are you running as admin? Etc.

Comment: didn't try it on vista yet. i ran this as an admin, of course. I believe that if there was a permission issue, regsvr32 would prompt a message rather than getting stuck.

Comment: regsvr32 loads your library and calls your implementation of DllRegisterServer. You can troubleshoot dependency loading issues with dependency walker's profiling support. If you loaded all dependencies fine, get a debugger, build a debug version and debug through your DllRegisterServer function using regsvr32 as the target program.

Comment: One of the possible causes is DEP-compliance. Old ATL COM base had issues with this, try to put the application on DEP exclusion list or otherwise temporarily disable DEP for check time.

Comment: Here is a discussion on Data Execution Prevention or DEP compliance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/350977/how-to-make-my-program-dep-compatible