# Trying to Connect to Quality Center using VS Express 2012 gives System.BadImageFormatException error

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, .net-4.0, visual-studio-2012, hp-quality-center

I am trying to Connect to Quality Center using a WPF application on Visual Studio Express 2012. My system configuration is Windows 7 64 bit.

I have added a reference to OTAClient.dll in the project. The Embedded Interop types property for this dll is set to true.

Searching for similar problems gave solutions like setting the project **target platform to x86**, but the solution didn't work for me.

I am getting the error

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {C5CBD7B2-490C-45F5-8C40-B8C3D108E6D7} failed due to the following
>   error: 800703e6 Invalid access to memory location. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x800703E6).

I also tried registering the dll using **regsvr32**.

Can someone help me with figuring out the problem.

Comment: I got the same problem too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Managed to solve this problem. This error has to some with DEP compatibility. The program is generating DEP exceptions and to clear it we have to clear IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_NX_COMPAT flag.

This can be done by adding post build event in Visual Studio

call $(DevEnvDir)..\tools\vsvars32.bat
editbin.exe /NXCOMPAT:NO $(TargetPath)

Refer stack over flow question [How to make my program DEP-compatible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350977/how-to-make-my-program-dep-compatible)